# Spring AOP using aspectj - How to log internal methods? How to include final method calls in your aspect class?Proper Exception handling in AOP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I used Spring AOP for logging service and encounter 3 problems:

1. Internal method logging:
   Ref code: [How to Log all the methods public method calls in AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042240/how-to-log-all-the-methods-both-public-and-private-method-calls-in-aop)
2. To include final methods in your proxies:
   Following the code standards mentioned in pmd, checkstyle and findbugs, we cannot change the final keyword for the methods. I tried interface and connecting to the call but do not work.
3. Handle exception, after that return to service itself for getting the actual response

```java
@RestController("/person")
public Person getpersonInfo() {
    try {
        // (...)
        getValidPerson();
        return response; // response including person info
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return response; // response stating the exception condition
    }
}
```

Please include your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I answered your question because I happened to know all the answers. But the Spring manual also knows them. So please RTFM before asking simple questions like these on StackOverflow. SO is about code and concreate problems in connection with software development. So please also learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are talking about [self-invocation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) such as `this.someOtherMethod()` (is the same without `this.`), it does not work because then you are not using the proxy. So either you configure Spring to expose the proxy objects and manually get a reference to the proxy before calling a method upon it or you switch from Spring AOP to [AspectJ with load-time weaving](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).
2. A proxy technically generates a subclass during runtime. But final classes cannot be extended and final methods not overridden. Thus you cannot handle them with proxies. Again, if you think you need this, switch to full AspectJ.
3. This can be done in an `@Around` advice like this:

```java
@Around("... your pointcut ...")
public Object myAdvice(final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    try {
        return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "some other object";
    }
}
```