# How to Log all the methods public method calls in AOP

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I have some issue in Logging all the methods when a service calls. Code is like this:

```java
package com.myproject.controller;
@RestController(/person)
public class Controller{
  public Person getpersonInfo(){
     ......
     getValidPerson();
  }
}

public Person getValidPerson() {

    isPersonValid(Person person);
    ....
}
```

Person class Methods :

```java
package com.myproject.dao;
public class Dao{
   public boolean isPersonValid(){
     //Checks for the person is Valid
   }
}
```

Aspect Class :

```java
package com.myproject;
@Component
@Aspect
public class Logging{

  @Before("execution(* com.myproject..*.*(..)))")
  public void beforeServiceCall(Jointpoint jp) {
    //Some Logging function
  }

}
```

Main class like this

```java
package com.myproject;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()
public class Main implements LoadTimeWeavingConfigurer{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  ......
  }
}
```

Pom file :

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I call the service http://localhost:8080/person - GET
getpersonInfo() is only Logged in this case, I have also tried 
LTW , but do not solve

> I need to log all internal methods to the service like is getValidPerson(),isPersonValid() mentioning all arguments to those invoked method.

Comment: You forgot to mention what is not logged but you exprect it to. Furthermore, your snippets are missing crucial parts of the information necessary to check whether the aspect is correct or not such as package name, class declaration incl. annotations. Short questions are good, but not too short, please. One thing I can already tell you, though: You should either use `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` for full AspectJ LTW or `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` for simple Spring AOP, but not both. BTW, private methods cannot be captured by Spring AOP, but I see no private methods in your code, so it does not matter.

Comment: I removed the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` it didn't work. May you suggest any other way to solve this issue

Comment: Read my previous comment and provide the information requested, please.

Comment: Please find my edited questions above mentioning the package and at the end of this question mentioned about methods that are not logged.If anything to be included please mention.